# How to factor $a^2-4b^2+4ac-8bc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am not sure how I would factor this. Can someone explain how I would factor this?

Comment: the trick is to express $4b^2$ as $(2b)^2$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Think about the terms $a^2-4b^2$. And $a-2b$ inside it.

Comment: +1 very nice, dear friend! Good to see you before I head off to bed!! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks. Are u feeling well now?

Comment: Yes, much better! Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd factor the first 2 terms which is a difference of squares one way and then the next pair with a common factoring and see if something common pops up:

$ a^2-4b^2+4ac-8bc = (a+2b)(a-2b)+4c(a-2b) = (a-2b)(a+2b+4c) $

Notice that the $a-2b$ is a common factor in the second part that allows for another step to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Soln: $$\begin{align*}
a^2 - 4b^2 + 4ac -8bc &= (a - 2b)(a + 2b) + 4c(a-2b)\\
                      &= (a - 2b)(a + 2b + 4c)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

$$a^2-4b^2+4ac-8bc=a^2+4ac+4c^2-4b^2-8bc-4c^2$$
$$=(a^2+4ac+4c^2)-4(b^2-2bc+c^2)$$